# Firebase database list search

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Image of Database in Console]

I have a firebase database and I need to make a query so that I search all of the "groups" for a specific value under "groupIDs", this will then allow me to retrieve the "group key" (eg KaejbPy6EBIGYEyu0S9), What i cant figure out is how to structure my query so that I target "groupIDs"

I am using Android Studio.

Thanks

Comment: If you have an array in your database and find you want to test if it contains a specific *value*, you probably should store the data in a set structure instead. Since your groups look similar to categories, I recommend using the structure I modeled in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Hi Frank, that worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Good to hear Nisal. I marked your question as a duplicate, since there's little sense in answering it again. :-)